# Function to add two numbers in awk

Tags: awk

I have an awk file `add.awk` which contains a function `add(num1,num2)`.
I want to take input from the command line.

```awk
#!/bin/awk -f
function add(num1,num2)
{
    print $num1 + $num2
}
BEGIN {
    add($1,$2)
}
```

But when I try to execute the file add.awk using the following command:

```
./add.awk 5,6
```

it always prints the value 0.

Is there any problem with the way I am specifying the input?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues, I think

First, as far as I know command line arguments are not available as `$1` and `$2` inside the `BEGIN` block. However, at least in GNU awk you can access them via the `ARGV` array (although they would need to be whitespace separated rather than comma separated).

Second, the syntax for de-referencing internal variables is just `num1` not `$num1`.

So you could do

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function add(num1,num2)
{
    print num1 + num2
}
BEGIN {
    add(ARGV[1],ARGV[2])
}
```

and then call it as

```
$ ./add.awk 5 6
11
```

If you really want to use `./add.awk 5,6` then you would need to split `ARGV[1]` into an array internally e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function add(num1,num2)
{
    print num1 + num2
}
BEGIN {
    split(ARGV[1],a,",");
    add(a[1],a[2])
}

$ ./add.awk 5,6
11
```

Comment: `ARGV` is POSIX (based on `nawk` the _new_ (1985) `awk`, won't work on the `/bin/awk` of Solaris from the 70s but will work with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` there and with about every other `awk` on other systems).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the clarification - your detailed knowledge of these things always amazes

Answer (score 4):

awk is reading from input stream, but as there is nothing it print 0.
In order to give input to your script you could use :

```
echo 5 6 | awk  '{ print $1 + $2}'
```